# How to perform functions on a dataframe that is itself a result of a function (R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I've built some code that performs simple arithmetic on three columns of numeric data of a dataframe (TypeChart) and binds it to the row names of the dataframe:

```
TypeCombo <- function(type1, type2, type3) {
  data.frame(Type = row.names(TypeChart), Effectiveness = TypeChart[,type1] * TypeChart[,type2] * TypeChart[,type3])
}
```

This produces a dataframe with a "Type" character vector (always fixed) and an "Effectiveness" numerical vector that varies depending on my inputs. I want to create a function that groups "Type" cells with the same "Effectiveness" value, but I'm not sure how to do this given the values change based on TypeCombo's inputs. It is also worth noting that the only values "Effectiveness" can take on are 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, and 8. How do I do this specific task, and more generally how does one go about building functions that act on variable lists/arrays/dataframes?

Comment: You can add a group by condition and then summarise with a list column or paste i..e `data.frame(Type = row.names(TypeChart), Effectiveness = TypeChart[,type1] * TypeChart[,type2] * TypeChart[,type3]) %>% group_by(Effectiveness) %>% summarise(Type = toString(Type))`

Comment: Is there a particular package I need for this to work? It doesn't seem like `%>%`, `group_by`, or `summarize` are defined by default in R

Comment: you need `library(dplyr)`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).